# How to remove sonarqube equals and hashcode duplicate code validation?

Tags: java, sonarqube

is there any regex or configuration that I can tell the sonarqube, not to consider the equal and hashcode methods in the analyze?

Comment: What is the version of the SonarJava plugin you're using?

Comment: Hi @janos, the version is 5.8 (build 15699)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Quality Profiles` > `Profile` that you selected and search for the rule finally unchecked it.
All as administrator

Comment: Hi Jose, in fact, clarifying my question, I need sonar not to consider equal and hashcode as "duplicate code".